# How to create CSS file within PHP code

Tags: php, html, css, file

How can I create a CSS file within PHP code without adding it to current codebase? This means I want to create a .CSS file using PHP code with a string as the file contents.

Comment: question's unclear. have any code to share?

Comment: I tried to not use code to make this as clear as possible. In my PHP code I want to create a CSS file using PHP variables

Comment: sorry, I for one am unable to provide you with anything. Wait for someone who knows what you're asking. Good luck

Comment: ...you have a few answers below, check that out. Could be the "magic" answers ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more digging it looks like the best way to create a file within PHP is with tmpname and tmpfile. I will be using tmpfile as a place to write my CSS code onto. Then I can use sys_get_temp_dir to get the directory. This will give me the same flexibility as with any $_FILE submitted from a form.

Answer (score 5):

I think you're looking for 'file_put_contents',
see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

I assume you want to take the values the user has entered using some sort of form?
From that as a PHP string create your css declarations

Then using the file_put_contents function write the string to the css file.

```
$cssString = '.selector { background-color: '.$userSubmittedBackgroundColor.'; }';
file_put_contents('populated.css', $cssString);
```

**EDIT:**

Alternatively you create the base .css file and swap in the parameters using string_replace or something similar. I guess you will want to do multiple replacements at once, so see the 'strtr' function, its basically a string replace but takes in an array of key value pairs as replacement tokens and values.

base.css

```
.selector { background-color: [*backgroundColorPlaceholder*]; }
```

PHP

```
$cssString = file_get_contents('base.css');
$cssString = str_replace('[*backgroundColorPlaceholder*], $userSubmittedBackgroundColor, $cssString);
file_put_contents('populated.css', $cssString);
```

Comment: I think file_put_conents is what I was looking for! Will this allow me to create the CSS file without it being applied to the HTML immediately? (I'm trying to generate the CSS file within PHP so I can upload the file to AWS

Answer (score 1):

https://css-tricks.com/css-variables-with-php/

On this page he seems to have a solution. Basically he links to a php page as the stylesheet `<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/style.php' />` and at the top of the php page puts a header that sets it back to css. He did say he had trouble with WordPress though so your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

do you mean something like this?

```
   $cssContent = '.myClass { color:red; }' .
                 'body { border-color: green }'

    file_put_contents('style.css', $cssContent);
```

Comment: This code will completely overwrite the CSS file!

Comment: file_put_contents('style.css', $cssContent, FILE_APPEND);